# Rails collection_select "selected" value is cancelled out by the default "prompt"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Couldn't find any reference to my problem in the API, so here goes:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, 
                        :name, {prompt: true}, { selected: @selected_value } %>
```

My users arrive to the form from different links, and depending on the link, they get their categories pre-selected for them from the @categories set. Sometimes they come from a general page, so instead of a pre-selected option they see the default prompt.

Problem: with my current code prompt replaces the selected value. 
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried flipping the hashes?  `<%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, { selected: @selected_value }, {prompt: true} %>`

Comment: i did, in that case prompt stops working. I will be trying to put a conditional in there somewhere I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went with placing a conditional inside my collection_select and now it works fine

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, 
    @selected_category ? {prompt: "Your text"} : {selected: @selected_category} %>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Don't forget to accept your answer since this was the solution!

Comment: Thanks:) I will in two days :D